# How can I decrypt an encrypted configuration value?

Tags: magento2, module, system-configuration, encryption-key

This is the code that I'm using to get the value from a specific field saved via the admin panel.

```
protected $_paymentData;
protected $_scopeConfig;
protected $logger;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleListInterface $moduleList,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
    \Stripe\Stripe $stripe,
    \Inchoo\Stripe\Model\StripeFactory $stripeFactory,
    array $data = array()
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $extensionFactory,
        $customAttributeFactory,
        $paymentData,
        $scopeConfig,
        $logger,
        $moduleList,
        $localeDate,
        null,
        null,
        $data
    );
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->initializeData($data);
}
 public function getPaymentKey(){
   $key= $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/webpay/keyid');
    echo $key;
    exit; 
}
```

**Echo Result:** idfrk3-45pfnrkhwneirgplbmisniepssnie:hirtw45

**True Key:** p92GBhcQl7TklHOsWcxBk4eOmL6wpQWBG9nT2Qcf

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Finally Get Success In Decrypt code...

```
protected $_encryptor;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor,
) {
    $this->_encryptor = $encryptor;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
$test = 'dfrk3-45pfnrkhwneirgplbmisniepssnie';
$test = $this->_encryptor->decrypt($test);
echo $test;
```

Share and help others..

Comment: It returns blank value. How can i get output in readable format?

Comment: can you share issue code?

Comment: This is not the best approach. This should be fixed through configuration as described in answer of Pmclain.

Answer (score 43):

`\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::getValue` will return the decrypted value. When `ScopeConfigInterface::getValue` returns an encrypted value, the configuration option is setup **incorrectly**. A correct implementation of an encrypted configuration value is:

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

Here we add an obscure configuration value in the path `payment/webpay/keyid` the critical things here is ensuring the `field` has `type="obscure"` and uses `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted` for the `backend_model`. This is how Magento knows to use a masked form field and encrypt any user input on save.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="webpay">
                <field id="keyid" translate="label" type="obscure" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Key Id</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

Adding `backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted"` here tells Magento the config value should be decrypted when retrieved with `ScopeConfigInterface::getValue`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <webpay>
                <keyid backend_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted"></keyid>
            </webpay>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

This adds the configuration path to the sensitive array and prevents the path's value from being included when dumping the store configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config\TypePool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sensitive" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="payment/webpay/keyid" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: There seem to be some scenarios where this doesn't work, in my case it was working before and it broke after I moved the field into an included group xml config. The above suggestions were implemented, but not working

Comment: @snez have you tried to re-save the configuration after you moved it?

Comment: pushing up as if the config path is not declared to sensitive, `Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface` unable to save proper obscured value to the database without using `Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface` when creating data patches

Answer (score 27):

If you have n98-magerun2.phar installed, you can get a decrypted config value with something like:

```
php bin/n98-magerun2.phar config:store:get --decrypt payment/webpay/keyid
```

You can also set encrypted config values from the command line with something like:

```
php bin/n98-magerun2.phar config:store:set --encrypt payment/webpay/keyid NEW_KEY_ID_VALUE_HERE
```

You can get n98-magerun2.phar from here:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Comment: isn't n98 the greatest thing ?

Comment: This also works in n98-magerun (for Magento 1)

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to decrypt some value using some key.
Put below code into decrypt-config-value.php in the root of your magento project.
This code need 2 constants to work properly

1. **ENV_CRYPT** is the environment crypt key, you can find this in the file app/code/env.php. Remember EACH environment has a different key, so you CAN'T get the production value with the staging key. You MUST use the production key to get production values. Line 21.
2. **PATH_ENC_DATA** is the path where the encrypted variable is saved. Line 24.

```php
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


######################################################################################################################

/**
 * ONLY 2 REQUIREMENTS
 */
// Available in the file: app/etc/env.php crypt => key =>
const ENV_CRYPT = 'e601ed01ef0c5a8766d373fdc4f8b23d';

//Path where is located the encrypted data
const PATH_ENC_DATA = 'path/to_encrypted/data';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterfaceFactory $ef
 */
$ef = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterfaceFactory');

class CustomDeploymentConfig extends \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig
{
    public function get($key = null, $defaultValue = null)
    {
        return ENV_CRYPT;
    }
}

/**
 * @var CustomDeploymentConfig $d
 */
$d = $objectManager->get(CustomDeploymentConfig::class);

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $e
 */
$e = $ef->create(['deploymentConfig' => $d]);

$resourceConnection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();
$query = "SELECT value FROM core_config_data WHERE path = '" . PATH_ENC_DATA . "';";
$result = $connection->fetchOne($query);

echo ">>>", $e->decrypt($result), "<<<\n";
```

Run **php decrypt-config-value.php** using console.

Answer (score 0):

`You can try with below method for payment encryption method to get value`,

You have to replace `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,` with below class path, `\Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface`
This is works fine,

```
   <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Gateway\Http;

use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Http\TransferBuilder;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Http\TransferFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Http\TransferInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface;

class TransferFactory implements TransferFactoryInterface
{
    private $config;

    private $transferBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $config,
        TransferBuilder $transferBuilder
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->transferBuilder = $transferBuilder;
    }


    public function getPaymentKey()
    {
        echo $this->config->getValue('payment/webpay/keyid')
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this work for you?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface in E:\wamp\www\magento2_8\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 73

Comment: have you solved problem?

Comment: no getting  
Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Payment\Gateway\ConfigInterface in E:\wamp\www\magento2_8\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\De‌​veloper.php on line 73  error.

Comment: try with above updated code and remove var folder.

Comment: ok..i will checking.

Comment: not work again..same error.

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code for json decode value,

```
class Paymentmodule
{
    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;

    public function __construct(
        ..//
        \Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder
    ) {
        ..//
        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
    }

    public function getPaymentKey()
    {
        $key= $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/webpay/keyid');
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($key);
        echo $key;
    }

}
```

Comment: Decoding failed: Syntax error";i:1;s:10720:"#0 E:\wamp\www\magento2_8\vendor\magento\framework\Json\Decoder.php(20): Zend_Json::decode('0:2:234SyEIM4aj...')
#1 E:\wamp\www\magento2_8\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success.php(58): Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder->decode('0:2:234SyEIM4aj...')

Comment: any idea about this error?

Comment: i have no idea about it, because this is for payment method, i have worked for above method for simple query

Comment: syntax error i think define another types.

Comment: working fine in simple query??

Comment: yes its working fine when encode from json, i have try for product detail page config options decode

Comment: ok..i have use key in system config...<field id="keyid" translate="label" type="obscure" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>LlaveID (KeyID)</label>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model>
                </field>

Comment: <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Encrypted</backend_model> to encryption bt not get perfect when direct scopcofig use.

Comment: i have update my answer plz check below code

Comment: i will checking.

Comment: plz check below answer

Comment: Not working Below 2 answers..any other idea?